# PAGEMETHODS is not working from JS function

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, code-behind, pagemethods

I am trying to call code behind method from JS function using pagemethods but its not calling and its not throwing any error either...

```
function example(){

pagemethods.method();
}

**aspx.cs
[webmethod]
public static void method(){

//some logic
}
```

so to find the issue i did some negative testing for that

1. I commented WEBMETHOD then it showed an error by saying"object does not support this property or method".can  i assume this case shows pagemethods is working!!!
2. Then I replaced calling method name in JS function to pagemethods.newmethod() but i didn't change method name to newmethod..i was expecting an some error but it didn't give me an error..

NOTE:i have "method=post" in form declaration..does it effect pagemethods anything..

so confused why this issue is happening!!!

can we call codebehind method in any other way instead of pagemethods..please advice!!!

Comment: why you think that its not calling?

Comment: try see [sample `Calling Static Methods in an ASP.NET Web Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i am debugging code with breakpoints so i dont see that static method got invoked which ever am calling using pagemethods.i am using same concept that got mentioned in "Calling Static Methods in an ASP.NET Web Page"

Comment: can you provide your markup?

Comment: am able to  call methods using pahemethods in sample project but when i use same logic in my actual project it is not working..could u tell me is there any other way i can call those methods from javascript..

Answer (score 3):

in [msnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can see a sample of this, so you need...

in markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    <Scripts >
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="pm.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

in code behind: your static method, with attribute `[WebMethod]`

in `pm.js`: something like this

```
function example(){
    PageMethods.method();
}
```

**UPDATE**
Another variant is use an ajax request to your method, for example with jquery in goes like this:

```
function CallMethod(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "YourPage.aspx/yourmathod",
        data:JSON.stringify({}), // parameters for method
        success: function (dt) { alert(dt);}, //all Ok
        error: function () { alert('error'); } // some error
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might be missing EnablePageMethods = true in your aspx page...

Comment: thanks for u reply..i enabled that attribut if i dont include that attribute pagemethods itself gives me error..could u tell me is there any other way i can call those methods from javascript..

Answer (score 0):

Below given code worked for me.

.cs -

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string yourmethod1()
    {
         return "Allow user";
    }
}
```

apsx.cs Page -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head runat="server">

    <title></title>

     <script type="text/javascript">

        function GreetingsFromServer()
        {
            PageMethods.yourmethod1(OnSuccess, OnError)
        }
        function OnSuccess(response)
        {
            alert(response);
        }
        function OnError(error) 
        {
            alert(error);
        }
    </script>

</head>


<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server"  method="post" >

    <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"  EnablePartialRendering="true"  > </asp:ScriptManager>

            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick=" return GreetingsFromServer();" />

    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web.conf -

```
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
           <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

    <system.web>

            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />

            <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />

            <authorization>
                       <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>

    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is also working -

.aspx file -

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Newtonsoft.Json" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function CallMethod()
        {
            debugger;


                jQuery.ajax({

                    url: 'Default.aspx/yourmethod',
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({}), // parameters for method
                    success: function (dt)
                    {
                        debugger;
                        alert('success : ' + dt.d  );

                    }, //all Ok
                    error: function (dt) {
                        debugger;
                        alert('error : ' + dt);
                    } // some error

                });


        }

        function GreetingsFromServer()
        {
            PageMethods.yourmethod1(OnSuccess, OnError);
        }
        function OnSuccess(response)
        {
            debugger;
            alert(response);
        }
        function OnError(error) {
            alert(error);
        }


    </script>


<script language="C#" runat="server">

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]  
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string yourmethod()
    {
        var settings = new Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.RedirectMode.Off;
        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Allow user");
        return json;
    }


     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]  
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
      public static string yourmethod1()
    {
        //string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Allow user");
        // or
        return "Allow user";
    }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
        <div>

            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"  EnablePartialRendering="true"  > </asp:ScriptManager>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="return GreetingsFromServer();" />
             <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" onclick="return CallMethod();" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web.conf -

```
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
           <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

    <system.web>

            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />

            <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />

            <authorization>
              <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>

    </system.web>

</configuration>
```